# How to display text below icon box?

Tags: html, css

I am beginner and learning css.I have two questions.

1. I want to display text below icon box but it's coming right side of
   each icon. what mistake am i doing?
2. I am using display flex,alignItem center, justify content in 3
   classes(body ,wrapper, item). Looks like i'm repeating code. Can you suggest good practice?

```css
body {
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
}
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.item {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    margin: 2px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

.item:hover {
    background-color: #F0F1F7;
    transform: scale(1.3);
}

.icon {
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: rgb(105, 204, 211);
    color: white;
}
.text{
    padding-top:10px;
    display: inline-flex;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="item">
            <i class="icon material-icons">directions_bike</i>
            <small class="text">Bicycle</small>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <i class="icon material-icons">backup</i>
            <small></small>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <i class="icon material-icons">email</i>
            <small></small>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <i class="icon material-icons">airplanemode_active</i>
            <small></small>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <i class="icon material-icons">insert_chart</i>
            <small></small>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Try removing ```display: flex;``` in css class ```.item``` ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest adding `flex-direction: column;` to your `.item` class.

```
.item {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    margin: 2px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
```

Here's a codepen: https://codepen.io/josh_minkler/pen/wvvZYeM

CSS tricks has a great guide to flexbox [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)